# Add days to a date and computing the difference doesn't lead to expected result

Tags: swift, date, gregorian-calendar

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. If you run this code in a Xcode Playground (I'm using 11.1) you will see it failing for random dates that, in my system, happen to be somewhere after 6500 days added to the current date. 
However those dates aren't fixed.

```swift
(1...10000).forEach { days in
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var dayComponent = DateComponents()
    dayComponent.day = days
    let date = Date()
    let someFutureDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: date)!

    let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date, to: someFutureDate)

    if (days != difference.day!) {
        print("WAT \(date) - \(someFutureDate) \(days) \(difference.day!)")
    }
}
```

Some output (failed from 130 to 160 times in my tests, output vary):

```
WAT 2019-10-31 14:01:47 +0000 - 2038-01-21 14:01:47 +0000 6657 6656
WAT 2019-10-31 14:01:47 +0000 - 2038-01-26 14:01:47 +0000 6662 6661
WAT 2019-10-31 14:01:47 +0000 - 2038-02-02 14:01:47 +0000 6669 6668
WAT 2019-10-31 14:01:47 +0000 - 2038-02-05 14:01:47 +0000 6672 6671
WAT 2019-10-31 14:01:47 +0000 - 2038-02-12 14:01:47 +0000 6679 6678
WAT 2019-10-31 14:01:47 +0000 - 2038-02-14 14:01:47 +0000 6681 6680
[snip]
```

Comment: Just use noon time for calendrical calculations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is due to rounding errors (note that a `Date` is internally represented as a floating point number holding the number of seconds since January 1, 2001). If you retrieve more components of the difference

```
let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond],
                                         from: date, to: someFutureDate)
```

then you'll notice that it is in the first example something like

```
day: 6656 hour: 23 minute: 59 second: 59 nanosecond: 999999755
```

which is *almost* the expected 6657 days. A possible fix seems to be to remove the “fractional part” of the date with

```
let date = calendar.date(bySetting: .nanosecond, value: 0, of: Date())!
```

or

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:
                Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.rounded())
```

With this change, I could not observe a difference anymore.

Comment: Oh, bugger, I was thinking in my mind: they would not be so stupid as to use floats, right? That's a bug from the start. OK, that the fix is indeed included is some kind of rehabilitation but still.